# How do I full screen with <embed>

Tags: html, embed

I am embedding a PDF on my site with the following code:

```
<embed src="{link_to_my_pdf}"
    type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="300" />
```

It has a height of 300px. If I click the fullscreen button on the PDF window, it doesn't full screen. It simply expands in the 300px window. How do I get it to fullscreen on my entire window?

Comment: Try this in your HTML: `<embed type="video/webm" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" width="400" height="300">`. Does it show up as fullscreen? (It might display **W3Schools refused to connect**)

Answer (score 2):

The button inside of the pdf window is not the fullscreen button it is the "fit to page" button, so the document will just expand to fill up its parent container. The fullscreen button is F11 but if the height of your pdf viewer is set to 300px the viewer will not fill up the whole screen after f11 is pressed.

A potential solution would be to open the pdf in a separate window from your site with a target="_blank" attribute on an a tag so that the pdf can be viewed in full screen mode and fill up the entire screen.

Also keep in mind that embed is a deprecated tag, I would suggest using either iframe or object, either of the following should work in all modern browsers:

iframe

```
<iframe src="some.pdf" style="min-height:100vh;width:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

object

```
<object data="some.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="min-height:100vh;width:100%"></object>
```

Here is a list of deprecated HTML tags for reference in the future:
https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/deprecated-html-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add `allowfullscreen` attribute to the `iframe` so that you can click fullscreen button in the HTML5 player toolbar to go fullscreen. Or you can use javascript to do it for you.
The code will be similar to this:

`<iframe allowfullscreen src="path/to/pdf" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>`

Here, position is specifically declared to make the file completely fit the window. Change the position attributes as needed.